# Refresh Materialized Views Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, materialized-views

I am running into the following error

```
    SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Assert
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   mv_query != "" - Expected non-empty MV CTAS
  query:     0
  location:  refresh.cpp:1570
  process:   padbmaster [pid=14118]
```

whenever I execute the SQL statement **REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW <viw_name>** in AWS Redshift. The views themselves are not empty so I do not really know how to resolve this. Would appreciate some help here

Comment: I think it's saying that it is running a `CREATE TABLE AS` (CTAS), but it is empty. Check your underlying views. You might need to recreate the views.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that's the approach I went with and it worked. I dropped the views, recreated them and the refresh worked smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you encounter the error, best fix is to drop your views, recreate them and then re-run the refresh materialized views statement.